# converting code to be able to use Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a rather long question I hope I can get help with.

I have a code that runs a simulation by a "while true" loop and after that a "for" loop that saves data from the simulation and restart the sim after given time. This code works fine, but now Im trying to convert this into a multiprocess where I can get 4 simultaneous simulations and for loops. So I tried to put most of the code into a function and then called it but it does not seem to work. Sorry for the long code I appreciate any help!

The first working code without multiprocessing

```
for z in range(8):
    for q in range(100):
        time_re = time_re + 3000
        tk.after(time_re,appender)
        tk.after(time_re,restart)
    ava(avaR1)


while True:
    time_steps = range(0,iterations+1)
    B = Beta.get()
    G = Gamma.get()
    D = Diff.get()
    M = Mor.get()

    steps_x_or_y = np.random.rand(n)
    steps_x = steps_x_or_y < D/2
    steps_y = (steps_x_or_y > D/2) & (steps_x_or_y < D)
    nx = (x + np.sign(np.random.randn(n)) * steps_x) % l
    ny = (y + np.sign(np.random.randn(n)) * steps_y) % l



    for i in np.where( (S==1) & ( np.random.rand(n) < B ))[0]:     # loop over infecting agents
         S[(x==x[i]) & (y==y[i]) & (S==0)] = 1         # Susceptiples together with infecting agent becomes infected

    S[ (S==1) & (np.random.rand(n) < G) ] = 2         # Recovery

    S[ (S==1) & (np.random.rand(n) < M) ] = 3         # Death

    nrInf1 = sum(S==1)
    nrSus.append(sum(S==0))
    nrInf.append(sum(S==1))
    nrRec.append(sum(S==2))
    nrRec1 = sum(S==2)
    nrDea = sum(S == 3)
    iterations += 1

    tk.update()
    tk.title('Infected:' + str(np.sum(S==1)))
    x = nx                                              # Update x
    y = ny                                              # Update y
```

The second code with me trying to change it to multiprocessing

```
def main1(i):

    # Physical parameters of the system
    x = np.floor(np.random.rand(n)*l)          # x coordinates
    y = np.floor(np.random.rand(n)*l)          # y coordinates
    S = np.zeros(n)                  # status array, 0: Susceptiple, 1: Infected, 2: recovered
    I = np.argsort((x-l/2)**2 + (y-l/2)**2)
    S[I[1:initial_infected]] = 1              # Infect agents that are close to center
    nrRec1 = 0
    nrDea = []
    time_re = 0
    particles = []
    R = .5                           # agent plot radius
    nx = x                           # udpated x
    ny = y                           # updated y



    def restart():
        global S
        I = np.argsort((x-l/2)**2 + (y-l/2)**2)
        S = np.zeros(n)
        S[I[1:initial_infected]] = 1

    rest = Button(tk, text='Restart',command= restart)
    rest.place(relx=0.05, rely=.85, relheight= 0.12, relwidth= 0.15 )

    def ava(k,o):
        global b
        k.append(sum(o)/3)
        Beta.set(b)                                  # Parameter slider for mortality rate
        b += 0.03125
        #bSaver.append(b)

    def appender(o):
        nrDea1.append(nrDea)
        o.append(nrRec1)


    for j in range(n):     # Generate animated particles in Canvas
            particles.append( canvas.create_oval( (x[j] )*res/l,
                                                  (y[j] )*res/l,
                                                  (x[j]+2*R )*res/l,
                                                  (y[j]+2*R )*res/l,
                                                  outline=ccolor[0], fill=ccolor[0]) )

    if i == 1:
        b=0
        for z in range(3):
            for q in range(3):
                time_re = time_re + 1000
                tk.after(time_re,appender(nrSRec1))
                tk.after(time_re,restart)
            tk.after(9000,ava(avaR1,nrSRec1))

    elif i == 2:
        b=0.25
        for z in range(3):
            for q in range(3):
                time_re = time_re + 1000
                tk.after(time_re,appender(nrSRec2))
                tk.after(time_re,restart)
            tk.after(9000,ava(avaR2,nrSRec2))
    
    elif i == 3:
        b=.50
        for z in range(3):
            for q in range(3):
                time_re = time_re + 1000
                tk.after(time_re,appender(nrSRec3))
                tk.after(time_re,restart)
            tk.after(9000,ava(avaR3,nrSRec3))
    
    else:
        b=.75
        for z in range(3):
            for q in range(3):
                time_re = time_re + 1000
                tk.after(time_re,appender(nrSRec4))
                tk.after(time_re,restart)
            tk.after(9000,ava(avaR4,nrSRec4))



    while True:

            B = Beta.get()
            G = Gamma.get()
            D = Diff.get()

            steps_x_or_y = np.random.rand(n)
            steps_x = steps_x_or_y < D/2
            steps_y = (steps_x_or_y > D/2) & (steps_x_or_y < D)
            nx = (x + np.sign(np.random.randn(n)) * steps_x) % l
            ny = (y + np.sign(np.random.randn(n)) * steps_y) % l

            for i in np.where( (S==1) & ( np.random.rand(n) < B ))[0]:     # loop over infecting agents
                S[(x==x[i]) & (y==y[i]) & (S==0)] = 1         # Susceptiples together with infecting agent becomes infected

            S[ (S==1) & (np.random.rand(n) < G) ] = 2         # Recovery
            nrDea= sum(S == 3)
            nrRec1 = sum(S==2)

            tk.update()
            tk.title('Infected:' + str(np.sum(S==1)))
            x = nx                                              # Update x
            y = ny                                              # Update y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1=mp.Process(target=main1, args=(1,))
    p1.start()
    p2=mp.Process(target=main1, args=(2,))
    p2.start()
    p3=mp.Process(target=main1, args=(3,))
    p3.start()
    p4=mp.Process(target=main1, args=(4,))
    p4.start()
    joinedList = avaR1+avaR2+avaR3+avaR4
    print(joinedList)

Tk.mainloop(canvas)
```

Comment: Have you considered running your original script 4 times in parallel (e.g. in 4 different terminals?)

Comment: your code uses a lot of numpy functions, so i'd recommend you change `sum` to `np.sum` and use numpy consistently everywhere then use threading instead of multiprocessing, you'll get some speedup and your code will work as expected, going down the multiprocessing rabbit hole isn't really that simple for the code above.

Comment: Yes that is true, but is it really that impossible to change my code to work with multiprocessing? Thought it would be useful to learn to use multiprocessing, as im really new to coding.

Comment: @MichealTheMagic you should start learning multiprocessing on simpler examples, like functions that do a simple calculation and return it, because multiprocessing interacts with the operating system and IPC, and deals with pickle and some OS specific stuff you'll need to learn that before you start using it for such code as above, it's close to running 4 applications in parallel and expecting a button in one application to affect the other application, yes it's possible, but you'll need a few weeks/months experience to get it to work as expected.